# How to find the other $\delta$ in a limit?

Tags: limits

The question is-

Let $$ f(x)= x^2 - 5 $$ and $\epsilon>0$

Find $\alpha$ so that $$ |x-4|<Min[5, \alpha] \implies |f(x)-11|< \epsilon$$
Can somebody explain the steps briefly and provide any source to learn about finding $\delta$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\left|x-4\right| < 5$, so $|x|-|4|\leq|x-4|< 5
$
by the reverse triangle inequality. Then you have $|x|<9$ so $|x+4|\leq|x|+|4|=|x|+4<13$. 
You can then deconstruct $|f(x)-11|$:
$$
|f(x)-11|=|x^2-16|=|x+4||x-4|<13|x-4|
$$
Since we require that $|f(x)-11|<\epsilon$, $\alpha = \frac{\epsilon}{13}$ will work because $|f(x)-11|<13|x-4|<13\frac{\epsilon}{13} = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $|f(x)-11|< \epsilon$. This is $$|x^2-16| < \epsilon.$$ It can also be written as 
$$|(x-4)(x+4)| < \epsilon.$$

Furthermore we can say $|x-4| < \frac{\epsilon}{x+4}$. Now all you need to do is to solve for $\alpha$ such that 
$$\min(5,\alpha) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{x+4}.$$

Hint: you should think about how you would want to bound $\frac{\epsilon}{x+4}$ by controlling $x$.